# Can't login to ODK Central Admin panel

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, odk

My ODK central was working perfectly fine before I decided to update it to the recent release of ODK using this URL (https://docs.getodk.org/central-upgrade/), everything went fine. After the update, I couldn't sign into the admin account again, it keeps returning `Something went wrong: the server returned an invalid error.`

I'm using Docker version 20.10.12 on Ubuntu 20.04

I have tried this https://forum.getodk.org/t/cant-login-something-went-wrong-the-server-returned-an-invalid-error/27413/6 but no success

Below is a screenshot of the error
[image: screenshot]

After running `docker-compose logs` I got the following logs as shown below

[image: odk_log1]
[image: odk_log2]

Answer (score 0):

In the central directory type docker-compose logs --tail 50 services and send us the output

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).